# Best way to Syn Outlook Contacts with MySQL db with hundreds of contacts realtime

Tags: php, mysql, caldav

What is the best method of keeping my contacts in my Outlook update with every new contact created on my MySQUL database using PHP. If the script/client etc... already exists, let me know what its call or how to start building it.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/outlookcaldavsynchronizer/

that looks like it, but for MySQL database and phpbased

Answer (score 0):

If that OutlookCalDAVSynchronizer actually works for you, it is probably easiest to implement a `CardDAV` server in your PHP environment. This has the added benefit that any `CardDAV` client will work with your stuff, not just the synchroniser ...

For PHP a lot of the work has been done for you already, checkout: [sabre/dav](http://sabre.io):

> sabre/dav is the most popular WebDAV framework for PHP. Use it to create WebDAV, CalDAV and CardDAV servers.